# How to detect that the user has used speech input in iOS?

Tags: ios, speech-recognition, text-to-speech, uitextinput

I would like to detect when the user uses the iOS keyboard microphone to add text to a UITextField.  So, after the keyboard comes up for text input, as soon as they use the dictation microphone even once, a flag will be set indicating that they have used speech input.  I need to do this for usage analytics purposes.

I tried trapping `dictationRecordingDidEnd` according to this:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextinput

And ran into the same problem the author here had:
[dictationRecordingDidEnd never called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12268194/dictationrecordingdidend-never-called)

In that the method never seems to execute.  Is there another way to detect speech input?

Answer (score 1):

MyThis is an adopted protocol, so you need to override the method. This worked for me running under iOS 8.1.1:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyTextField : UITextField

@end


#import "MyTextField.h"

@implementation MyTextField

- (void) dictationRecordingDidEnd {
    printf("dictationRecordingDidEnd\n");
}

@end
```

Comment: Hope this is not a private method.